# Can’t SSH into my Digital Ocean droplet from Blink (iPadOS)

Tags: ipad, ssh, digital-ocean

I am following this guide: https://thesweetsetup.com/how-to-use-digital-ocean-for-web-development-on-an-ipad/ To setup an environment on an iPad using Blink/Mosh.

I generated a droplet in the DO UI and added the public key I created using `ssh-keygen` in blink (also tried `ssh-keygen -m pem`). When I do `ssh root@<IP-ADDRESS.` I get the usual dialog:

```
Ed25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:<key>.
The server is unknown.
Do you trust the host key? (yes/no): yes
This new key will be written on disk for further usage.
Do you agree? (yes/no): yes
```

After this I just get back to `blink`. If I try to SSH again nothing happens. If I try to say `ssh -i id_rsa root@<IP-ADDRESS>` also nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong? I found this: https://github.com/blinksh/blink/issues/725 But do not understand what to do to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. The blink terminal didn't give me any output or anything. The problem is that you have to give the full path of the `id_rsa` file (from the perspective of your default blink directory). So instead of `ssh -i id_rsa root@<IP-ADDRESS>`, do `ssh -i .ssh/id_rsa root@<IP-ADDRESS>`.

Btw one difference in our ssh key creation is that you created your key with the command `ssh-keygen -m pem` while I used `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096`. I don't think that should be a problem though.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue on some DO droplets I had. I had already set up the droplets with another key and added a new one for my blink app through the DO interface with no luck.
Realized that I had to still add the new public key to the authorized keys file in your users .ssh directory. ( ~/.ssh/authorized_keys ) and this solved my problem.

I did this through the device I was already using successfully, and copied to new key to that device to paste in.

Comment: You mean you had to copy the public key to the DO droplet or the iPad? I'd think the iPad as the client would want the private key, but the DO setup on iPad vs other OS's should not be a factor so I don't understand why the key would have to be entered to the DO authorized keys file. Would you mind elaborating?